# Syncing SQL server 2000 with 2005 -- will DTS still work?

Tags: sql-server-2005, synchronization, sql-server-2000, dts

we have a local staging server running sql server 2000 and a remote public version also running sql server 2000. The remote version will be upgraded to 2005 and I am wondering if the DTS packages we have in place will continue to function between the two machines?

If not, what would be the simplest, most efficient way to sync between the two?

We will not be upgrading the local server, and the upgrade of the remote one will be taking place very soon (not in our control).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your DTS packages reside on the local server, there shouldn't be an issue (aside from obvious changes to SQL itself (I.E. the old-school joins not working anymore)), and in fact, I've even seen developers save DTS packages on SQL 2005 databases though I'm sure it's not a very good idea.

EDIT:  It might also be worthwhile to check out [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=DF0BA5AA-B4BD-4705-AA0A-B477BA72A9CB&displaylang=en&displaylang=en) for the tools to design/modify DTS packages with SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: An example of an old school join that wouldn't work? Thank you!

Comment: The old-style left join syntax was deprecated as of SQL 2005 unless you run your databases in SQL 2000 compatibility mode.  Example:

SELECT  tableA.id, tableB.id 
FROM    tableA, tableB 
WHERE   tableA.id *= tableB.id

In this case, the non-ANSI-standard left outer join (*=) is deprecated.  You can still perform joins in the WHERE clause, just not using that *= operator.

Comment: You might also check here for a more complete list:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144262(SQL.90).aspx